# is it possible to open RSS feed links from other sites within my site?

Tags: php, rss, feed

I was just wandering if it is possible to open an RSS feed link from other sites within the same site that the RSS feed is displayed on?

for example:

i get the RSS feed from sky sport and display the images, title and link on my own website...
when someone clicks on the link for the RSS feed, they will be pointed to sky sport page for that news. Now, I was wandering if it is possible to open the news page within my own site instead of pointing the users/readers to sky's website?

i don't know but maybe using iframe?

this is how i get the RSS feed:

```
<?php
$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://www.fifa.com/rss/index.xml');
$limit = 1; // Change this number to however many items you want to display
$counter = 1;
if($rss)
{
$items = $rss->channel->item;
}
?>

<?php
$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://www.skysports.com/rss/0,20514,12010,00.xml');
$limit = 1; // Change this number to however many items you want to display
$counter = 1;
if($rss)
{
$items = $rss->channel->item;
}
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    if($counter <= $limit) {
  echo "<div style='border: solid #0C0 1px; width:150px; height:100px;'><img src=\"" . (string)$item->enclosure['url'][0] . "\" style='width:150px; height:100px;'></div>";
   echo "<p>" . $item->description . "</p>";


  $counter++;
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: an iframe would do it, or set a link target to open in a new window. you couldn't use a jquery `.load()` call, for instance, since that'd violate the same-origin security policy.